# How to power cycle a USB modem without rebooting?

Tags: command-line, usb, hardware, modem

I have a usb modem plugged into Mac Mini. I've found that rebooting the device or plugging the modem out and putting it in will change my IP, which is what I want. How do I power cycle the modem programmatically, without needing to reboot the Mac?

I'm using ZTE MF 833V

Comment: This depends on the specific model you are using and whether it supports this.

Comment: @nohillside, it's ZTE MF 833V

Comment: If you access the config page of the modem (should be http://192.168.100.1/ according to the manual), is there a reboot option? If yes, you might be able to use Applescript with UI scripting to trigger a reboot (or some JavaScript).

Comment: @nohillside, sadly there is no such option, is there anything on the OS side to just power off a generic USB device?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236580/turn-off-usb-power-on-os-x-mac-mini?rq=1 seems to indicate there isn't.